# Can I RSS a shared folder in a any local network?

Tags: file-sharing, rss

How can I build an RSS for a regular shared folder in a any local network? so I can get notify with any new file/folder in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Awasu](http://www.awasu.com) can do this via a [Channel Plugin](http://www.awasu.com/plugins.php).

Awasu's developer recently wrote a tutorial on how to do this exact task:

http://www.awasu.com/weblog/writing-extensions/